# Docker application Portability in Openshift

Tags: docker, dockerhub, openshift-origin

I need clarification on below points related to docker on Openshift:

1. Is docker supported in openshift origin or online as of now or it will be there in future release of V3? If yes, how does it work?
2. I have seen there are different docker images available for openshift in docker hub [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/openshift). How do these work?
3. Docker is mainly for provisioning application portability, say I already have an application running in my docker installed locally, so how can this be migrated to openshift environment, or, how in openshift docker can images be created?

Comment: May help : https://www.openshift.com/blogs/geard-the-intersection-of-paas-docker-and-project-atomic

Comment: Still about gearD : https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/openshift/geard/

Answer (score 2):

> Is docker supported in openshift origin or online as of now or it will be there in future release of V3? If yes, how does it work?

We just released the V3 repo here so it is in Origin https://github.com/openshift/origin.

> I have seen there are different docker images available for openshift in docker hub here. How do these work?

*You answered this in the comments, just clarifying here for visibility.*
Linux containers, or “Gears”, have always been a core component of OpenShift. Docker is new standard for containerization through the libcontainer project. To quote this great article https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-v3-platform-combines-docker-kubernetes-atomic-and-more:

The OpenShift v3 Cartridge format will adopt the Docker packaging model and enable users to leverage any application component packaged as a Docker image. This will enable developers to tap into the Docker Hub community to both access and share container images to use in OpenShift. Customers will also be able to leverage Red Hat certified container images from both Red Hat and our ISV partners. Our recently launched OpenShift Marketplace will expand to include solutions from both SaaS partners and certified ISV’s.
......
In OpenShift v3, we will be integrating Kubernetes in the OpenShift Broker to drive container orchestration.

> Docker is mainly for provisioning application portability, say I already have an application running in my docker installed locally, so how can this be migrated to openshift environment, or, how in openshift docker can images be created?

I'm quoting from the article again, but "The OpenShift v3 Cartridge format will adopt the Docker packaging model and enable users to leverage any application component packaged as a Docker image. This will enable developers to tap into the Docker Hub community to both access and share container images to use in OpenShift"

Comment: Hey one more doubt, can we test this origin V3 release with docker integration for creating applications, to check how it allows users to deploy application with docker files ? Thanks again!

Comment: The V3 Repo is live so you can give it a shot.

Comment: Hi Thankyou so much for continuous help , it will be really helpful if you can clarify these things too:Existing Cartridges availability - As I understand docker packages everything required to run an app in a single container, like I have a docker file which installs and deploys war file in Jboss server. So in newly OpenShift release having docker implemented will consist existing cartridges ( web,database etc) or user will have to install everything manually using docker images. &
Origin V3 is only for testing or can be used in production sites also?